# jQuery plugin naming convention (for the function)

Tags: jquery, naming-conventions

Which casing looks better to you for a jQuery plugin:

```
$("#foo").runMyPlugin();
```

or

```
$("#foo").runmyplugin();
```

Is there a naming convention for jQuery that prefers on over the other?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend you the first one, that convention is widely used in JavaScript, even in the core language by itself, the [ECMA Specification](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/) uses it, e.g.

```
Array.prototype.toLocaleString
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty
Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable
// etc...
```

All identifiers are named with *camelCase*, and only [constructor functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Creating_New_Objects/Using_a_Constructor_Function) are named with the first letter as capital (*PascalCase*).

Comment: Those examples look more like the first one?